# How does this pre increment on arrays work

Tags: java, arrays

```
++frequency[2] ;
```

I thought the default value of an array that hasn't been initialized is 0.
Imo, it means evaluate 
`frequency[2]` which is zero and then add 1 to it and assign it to the index 2.
Pls can anyone explain how the output for this code was gotten. Been hitting my head real hard on this.

```
 public static void main(String ars[])
{

    int responses[] = {1,2,4,4};
   int freq[] = new int[5];
    for(int answer = 1;answer < responses.length;answer++){
        ++freq[responses[answer]];
    }
    for ( int rating = 1; rating < freq.length; rating++ )
         System.out.printf( "%6d%10d\n", rating, freq[ rating ] );
```

//output

```
     1         0
     2         1
     3         0
     4         2
```

Comment: Well, what happens when you try it?

Comment: If you believe [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable), it says that, *Java does not have uninitialized variables. Fields of classes and objects that do not have an explicit initializer and elements of arrays are automatically initialized with the default value for their type (false for boolean, 0 for all numerical types, null for all reference types). Local variables in Java must be definitely assigned to before they are accessed, or it is a compile error.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are.

```
int[] frequency = new int[3];
System.out.println(frequency[2]);
System.out.println(++frequency[2]);
System.out.println(frequency[2]);
```

Prints:

```
0
1
1
```

EDIT: As lurker said here [How does this pre increment on arrays work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100474/how-does-this-pre-increment-on-arrays-work/32100808?noredirect=1#comment52096863_32100808), this answer is valid for Java, but it might not be for other languages.

Comment: But this demonstration doesn't *guarantee* it. It's possible to have this code execute the same way in C, for example, depending upon what memory happens to be. What *guarantees* it is the policy in the language regarding variable initialization.

Comment: I answered about Java, but yes, it will be better to point this in the example.